# Angular Guard Not Called on Route Path that Redirects

Tags: angular, angular-router, query-string, angular-router-guards

So, there can be entry to my app in multiple ways.

http://localhost:4200 and http://localhost:4200/home

If the link to my app (from an outside app) has a query param on it, I want to grab it.  I created a `QueryParamCheckGuard` which is `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root',})`.  For now, I just have a `console.log('In QueryParamCheckGuard');` in both the `canActivate` and `canActivateChild` methods to see when it gets called.  Right now, it's not getting called on any path that redirects.

In my app, I have sub-projects.  The main routing looks like this:

```
  {
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
    canActivateChild: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
    data: {
      path: 'App Home Path',
    },
    loadChildren:
      '../../projects/home-app/src/app/app.module#HomeAppModule',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
    canActivateChild: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
    data: {
      path: 'App Empty Path',
    },
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
```

In the HomeAppModule, the routing is this:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
    canActivateChild: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
    data: {
      path: 'Sub-proj Home Path',
    },
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
    ],
}
```

The routing all works correctly, but when I enter http://localhost:4200?id=test, the QueryParamCheckGuard is not being called on the main app's `path: ''` route that redirects to the main app's `path: 'home'` and by the time it gets to the sub-project's `path: 'home'`, the id query param is stripped off.  I know it's not getting called from the other routes because I added a path property to each path's data that identifies each path.  I then `console.log(route.data.path);`.

If I hit http://localhost:4200/home?id=test, the QueryParamCheckedGuard is hit and I can grab the id query param.  Aside from requiring all outside apps to call the /home url, am I missing something to get the path that redirects to home to grab the query param?

Answer (score 2):

So, I found out that this is an existing issue for about 3 years now.  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18605
Basically, guards don't get called on paths that redirect.

My way around this was to change `redirectTo: '/home',` to

```
data: {
  redirectTo: '/home',
},
children: [],
```

The reason for this is having `children:[]` allows the guard to be called.  Then, in the guard, I check if `route.data.redirectTo` exists, and if so, return a `UrlTree` with the value in `route.data.redirectTo`.

I also realized that changing the redirect on the main app's empty path was not doing anything.  I had to add an empty check on the HomeAppModule's routing and do it there.  I am now able to grab the query params and save them for when they are stripped after the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is dealing with the same issue as mentioned [here on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18605). Generally guards are NOT executed on redirect routes (routes with `redirectTo`).

A possible solution to circumvent this problem:
You could make the redirect route a child route of the route with the guards as follows:

```
{
  path: '',
  canActivate: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
  canActivateChild: [QueryParamCheckGuard],
  data: {
    path: 'App Empty Path',
  },
  pathMatch: 'full',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/home',
    }
  ]
}
```

Like this the guards will be executed on the "parent" with the empty path and then it will execute the redirect when matching the "child" route afterwards.